# NetBeans 6.9: C++ Console App.: Arguments not seen in debug mode

Tags: c++, debugging, console, netbeans-6.9, ubuntu-11.04

I am using Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I am developing a console op.and am building in debug mode.

The main function is declared as

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

In order to add the arguments, I right click on the project and select:
properties
run
arguments

and enter my arguments of which there are several.  However, when I get to the line

```
    for (i=1; i<argc; ++i) switch (argv[i][1])
```

I get

```
argc==1
```

That is,it is ignoring my arguments for some reason.

Comment: That's the value given b the NetBeans debugger.  Also, it does not do any cycles of the loop.

Comment: The argument has to be set in some project property dialog I guess, are you sure it's set in the correct place?

Comment: It's in Properties:Run:Arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cumbersome solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353764/c-netbeans-run-configuration-passing-arguments-issue) and a better solution [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic36082.html).